# chmod 400 will not change the permissions of a file

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have to change an RSA key file (`.pem`)'s permissions to `400` so I can use it to connect to an AWS EC2 instance but for some reason I cannot seem to do so. I am in the folder where the file is located and the command `sudo chmod 400 3dcitydb.pem` gives no output but has no effect on the file.

I even logged in as root and I still cannot do it:

```
root@ib:/media/isaac/Data/MOSS_application/aws_keys# sudo chmod 400 ./3dcitydb.pem 
root@ib:/media/isaac/Data/MOSS_application/aws_keys# ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 isaac isaac 1692 Jul  4 21:13 3dcitydb.pem
```

Any idea of what this could be? Any time I try to search this I either get people mistyping the chmod command, people unable to do so on an external hard drive due to a different partition system or people who didn't realize they had to change the file permissions in the first place.

Ubuntu version is 16.04

Comment: Is this on a NTFS drive?

Comment: I am assuming this is on an external drive because it is mounted to `/media/username`.  If you run `blkid` from a terminal window and find that mount the `type=` will tell you.  NTFS is not affected by chmod as shown in the link.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for doing so, or would it be significantly easier to just put it on the main drive?

Comment: Put it on the main drive if the security is that important for the file.